# Melt a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form of

```
id  Class Value
1    A     1.1
2    B     2.5
1    C     0.5
2    A     .11
2    C     5.1
3    A     1
```

What I am going to make is a new dataset like below:

```
id   Class.A Class.B Class.C
1     1.1     NA      0.5
2     .11     2.5     5.1
3     1       NA      NA
```

any ideas on how to do it quickly in R?

Comment: `?reshape2::dcast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in base R:

```
tapply(df$Value, list(df$id,df$Class), sum)

#     A   B   C
#1 1.10  NA 0.5
#2 0.11 2.5 5.1
#3 1.00  NA  NA
```

This will also do the job but puts `0` instead of `NA` for missing values:

```
xtabs(Value~., df)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Class = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(1.1, 2.5, 0.5, 0.11, 5.1, 1)), .Names = c("id", 
"Class", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```